# Multi DELETE из нескольких таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Как можно произвести мульти удаление из 2-х таблиц? Есть таблица отелей `tholidays` *(id)*, также имеется таблица `tholidaysimages` *(hotelid, imageid)* и 3-я таблица `timages` содержащая все картинки *(id,filename)*. При нажатии удаления отеля, хочу подчистить все базы, т.е. при нажатии мы имеем только *`ID`* отеля, после необходимо удалить картинку с таблицы `images` и `hotimages` но только в `hotimages` есть *hotelid*.

Остановился на ошибке но суть логики освещу:

```
DELETE I.id, TH.imgaeid FROM tholidays as H
LEFT JOIN tholidaysimages as TH on H.id=$hotelid
LEFT JOIN timages as I on TH.imageid= I.id
```

Господа покопавшись, понял, что с родительской удалять не нужно чтобы данные хранились, я добавил поле `status` подскажите как в данном случае строить запрос чтобы с 2-х таблиц шло удаление а в родительской проставлялся статус?

Comment: Используйте внешние ключи с ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: Добавил, вопрос один данная опция распространяется только на новые созданные записи?

Comment: В таблице нет "новых" и "старых" записей. Есть просто записи. И если у записи нет поля со штампом времени, то только по самой таблице и её данным невозможно определить, в каком порядке в неё вставлялись записи.

Comment: Sql запрос который вы написали полностью бессмысленен, внимательно прочитайте описание синтаксиса DELETE в документации к MySQL и посмотрите мой комментарий к ответу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо Всем! Решено!

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM timages WHERE timages.id IN
           ( SELECT tholidaysimages.imageid FROM tholidaysimages  
             WHERE tholidaysimages.hotelid = $hotelid)");
mysql_query("UPDATE tholidays set status=0 where id=".$hotelid);
```

Answer (score 0):

> с родительской удалять не нужно чтобы данные хранились, я добавил поле status подскажите как в данном случае строить запрос чтобы с 2-х таблиц шло удаление а в родительской проставлялся статус?

Удаление и обновление невозможно выполнить одним запросом. Посему это будут два запроса. Один на удаление, второй на обновление.

Comment: Так ведь я делаю функцию, а функция возвращает 1 значение. И еще вопрос - Как построить запрос на удаление если используется ON DELETE CASCADE и также обновление статуса??? Если возможно хотя бы некий пример, буду очень признателен

Comment: 1) При чём тут возврат значения? ни удаление, ни обновление ничего не возвращают, кроме количества записей, на которые повлияло выполнение запроса. 2) Текст запроса на удаление не зависит от наличия ON DELETE CASCADE.

Comment: @Den DELETE FROM timages WHERE timages.id IN (SELECT tholidaysimages.imageid FROM tholidaysimages WHERE tholidaysimages.hotelid = <идентификатор вашего отеля>); DELETE FROM tholidaysimages WHERE tholidaysimages.hotelid = <идентификатор вашего отеля>; UPDATE tholidays SET tholidays.status = 1 WHERE tholidays.id = <идентификатор вашего отеля>; как то так

Comment: Извиняюсь за молчание, спасибо fens! Но есть загвоздка, разными вариациями пытался сделать удаление с timages, update работает, 2-е удаление работает, а вот первое не получается. 
mysql_query("DELETE FROM tholidaysimages WHERE tholidaysimages.hotelid=".$hotelid);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM timages WHERE timages.id IN (SELECT imageid FROM tholidaysimages WHERE hotelid".$hotelid);
mysql_query("update tholidays set status=0 where id=".$hotelid);
Даже можно не делать второе удаление, Каскад и так его удалит, но проблема именно в 1-м удалении

Comment: Сам запрос DELETE FROM timages WHERE timages.id IN (SELECT tholidaysimages.imageid FROM tholidaysimages WHERE tholidaysimages.hotelid=
Был проверен, с SQL удаляется на Ура! Но в php нет(